A question about whether the verbs come/go require/prefer a directional such as 'here'
Can we say, "He comes/goes" instead of "He comes here/goes there." if the listener knows where that person comes/goes?

It wouldn't sound idiomatic in every situation, but in response to say "Does John go to Church at all?" the reply "He goes." is acceptable if rather curt. Often, more 'padding' is added before such short sentences sound natural.

@EdwinAshworth you mean like 'yes, he goes.' is more natural?

"Yes, he goes every Sunday" or "Yes, he does, but only on special occasions." It would be odd to answer with just "He goes".

@KateBunting Actually, I am just trying to know how far a sentence can be grammartically correct.

A sentence can be technically 'grammatically correct' (which 'He comes' and 'He goes' are), but not something that people are likely to say in real life.

That's certainly one (to my ears) far more natural-sounding variant. But 'She rides!' has become something of a template, licensing the unusual in certain registers.

There is also the possibility of "He comes!" announcing the arrival of some eagerly expected person.

I fear the OP was asking about responses to these verbs in questions, which he only clarified in his question to me.

"Come" and "go" have many other meanings, e.g. sexual and urinary and go=run/function, when they can be intransitive and without complements. You can also use "he is coming/going" to describe someone's current motion, but if you're only interested in "he comes/goes" (habitual meaning) that's irrelevant.

Yes, you can use the verbs to go and to come without specifying location so long as it is clear in context. Here are some examples of this wording:

Two restaurant workers are discussing a regular customer.
A: Harry must be running late at work. He usually comes at 5 pm sharp!


A married couple are discussing tasks they need to do
A: Can you run out to the grocery store? We need milk and eggs.
B: Sure, I'll go now.



Can we say, "He comes/goes" instead of "He comes here/goes there." if the listener knows where that person comes/goes?

Yes we can say like that -
Parent : When can I meet the principal?
Receptionist: He comes at 9 AM and goes at 4 PM.

Person 1: What exactly does he do?
Person 2: He comes, he goes.
OR
He comes and he goes.
Those have subject and predicate, here the verb come or go.

No, I meant wheather it is acceptable to use those verbs in separated sentences. As, 1. He goes. 2. He comes. In the sense, 1st person: Did he come here? 2nd person: He comes.

1st person:  What does he do?  2nd person.  He comes.  He goes.  He takes off his coat.  He puts his coat back on.  He is tedious to deal with.

@Salimuddin No, it's like this: Did he come here? Answer: Yes, he did or No, he didn't. But he comes here sometimes.

@CharlesB.Cameron That's basically what I said in my answer.

@what about this sentence : "It may not be my decision but if I am deciding then,yes, He goes."

Note:I have got this sentence in the link below* (https://www.theguardian.com/football/2011/sep/28/carlos-tevez-denies-refusing-play)


@Salimuddin I wonder why you move from one usage to another like that. First, learn the basics, then move on to the more advanced features. Also, please edit your question to reflect what you asked me above. That use is correct.

@Lambie I am Sorry for bothering you. Actually I am trying to know if there is any use of this kind of sentences.

@Salimuddin What type of sentences? You have changed the tenor of your questions. [any use for x]

Now I am asking about this sentence: "It may not be my decision but if I am deciding then' yes, he goes." Here they just used he goes. Then if it is possible using 'he goes.' alone?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
